# Installing osCommerce on CentOS

Tags: web-hosting, lamp, oscommerce

I want host my web site using osCommerce on CentOS, we have our own server at our office on that we have install CentOS 5.5 with LAMP. We want to host a web site using our live IP address using osCommerce.  If any one has a step by step how to for osCommerce on CentOS please share with us.

We have unzipped `oscommerce.zip -d /var/www/html/` and we can see the admin page. When people visit from outside, they also see the admin page.

Comment: This might be a better fit at http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you cannot get this right then you shouldn't be hosting your own e-commerce store. The Internet is rife with opportunists that will take advantage of your insecure server. Get a proper host.

Comment: Seriously, you're putting all of your customers at risk by hosting this yourself without knowing what you're doing. Either hire a qualified system admin, or (the far cheaper option) get a shared hosting account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Once you unzip the files, the installation is the default operation. I am assuming you see an installation screen. Or have you already done the installation?
2. after installation remove the install directory.
3. After install the admin is accessible from http:///admin/ It should not be visible directly at http:///. If you are facing such an issue it is pretty strange.
4. You can always rename the admin directory as you wish and make changes in the admin/includes/configure.php. That will help you setup a secure admin to start with.

Answer (score 1):

A quick [Google search turns up lots of tutorials](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=install+oscommerce). [This one came up first](http://forums.oscommerce.com/topic/162231-quick-install-guide/) and looks good.